# Highlighting maximum value in a column on a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a `seaborn.heatmap` plotted from a `DataFrame`:

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
sns.heatmap(collected_data_frame, annot=True, vmax=1.0, cmap='Blues', cbar=False, fmt='.4g')
```

I would like to create some sort of highlight for a maximum value in each column - it could be a red box around that value, or a red dot plotted next to that value, or the cell could be colored red instead of using `Blues`. Ideally I'm expecting something like this:

[image]

I got the highlight working for DataFrame printing in Jupyter Notebook using tips from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606458/python-pandas-highlighting-maximum-value-in-column):

[image]

How can I achieve a similar thing but on a heatmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete solution based on the answer of @r-beginners:

#### Generate `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import seaborn

arr = np.array([[0.9336719 , 0.90119269, 0.90791181, 0.3112451 , 0.56715989,
        0.83339874, 0.14571595, 0.36505745, 0.89847367, 0.95317909,
        0.16396293, 0.63463356],
       [0.93282304, 0.90605976, 0.91276066, 0.30288519, 0.56366228,
        0.83032344, 0.14633036, 0.36081791, 0.9041638 , 0.95268572,
        0.16803188, 0.63459491],
       [0.15215358, 0.4311569 , 0.32324376, 0.51620611, 0.69872915,
        0.08811177, 0.80087247, 0.234593  , 0.47973905, 0.21688613,
        0.2738223 , 0.38322856],
       [0.90406056, 0.89632902, 0.92220635, 0.3022458 , 0.58843012,
        0.78159595, 0.17089609, 0.33443782, 0.89997103, 0.93128579,
        0.15942313, 0.62644379],
       [0.93868063, 0.45617598, 0.17708323, 0.81828266, 0.72986428,
        0.82543775, 0.41530088, 0.2604382 , 0.33132295, 0.94686745,
        0.05607774, 0.54141198]])

columns_text = [str(num) for num in range(0,12)]
index_text = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5']
arr_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=columns_text, index=index_text)
```

#### Highlighting maximum in a column:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 3), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = seaborn.heatmap(arr_data_frame, annot=True, vmax=1.0, vmin=0, cmap='Blues', cbar=False, fmt='.4g', ax=ax)

column_max = arr_data_frame.idxmax(axis=0)

for col, variable in enumerate(columns_text):
    position = arr_data_frame.index.get_loc(column_max[variable])
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((col, position),1,1, fill=False, edgecolor='red', lw=3))
    
plt.savefig('max_column_heatmap.png', dpi = 500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

#### Highlighting maximum in a row:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 3), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = seaborn.heatmap(arr_data_frame, annot=True, vmax=1.0, vmin=0, cmap='Blues', cbar=False, fmt='.4g', ax=ax)

row_max = arr_data_frame.idxmax(axis=1)

for row, index in enumerate(index_text):
    position = arr_data_frame.columns.get_loc(row_max[index])
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((position, row),1,1, fill=False, edgecolor='red', lw=3))

plt.savefig('max_row_heatmap.png', dpi = 500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't comment on the fact that if there was more than one maximum value, it needed to be addressed in the list. That's a good example of a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the post! I applied the one for row maximums in my own work. Additionally I included row minimums (maximums in red and minimums in blue). Works brilliantly except that when min and max are neighboring cells, the edge that was drawn latest will be drawn over the previous one. I wonder if there is a "dodge" option available to avoid drawing over?

Answer (score 2):

We've customized the heatmap examples in the [official reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/heatmap_annotation.html). The customization examples were created from the responses from [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290778/add-custom-border-to-certain-cells-in-a-matplotlib-seaborn-plot). It's a form of adding parts to an existing graph. I added a frame around the maximum value, but this is manual.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Load the example flights dataset and convert to long-form
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((10,6),2,2, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))
```

[image]

max value:

```
ymax = max(flights)
ymax
1960

flights.columns.get_loc(ymax)
11
xmax = flights[ymax].idxmax()
xmax
'July'
xpos = flights.index.get_loc(xmax)
xpos
6

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((ymax,xpos),1,1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))
```

Comment: Hi, this is indeed something that I need, but how could I automate this so that it adds the rectangles by itself?

Comment: You can use additional code to get it automatically.